# Providing parameters to functions in reactive shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to provide *parameters* to reactive to make it work like normal functions. I am providing a piece of code of what I am trying to achieve. First, I create a reactive data where the user can select a project and a date range and the data gets updated upon click of the 'apply' button. Inside this reactive I wrap the data inside a function(x) which I call in the filter and most importantly group_by.

```
holidays <- reactive({input$apply
  function(x){
  isolate(
  data() %>%
    filter(x != non_holiday,
        project %in% input$projects &
          date >= input$sell_date[1] &
          date <= input$sell_date[2]
    ) %>%
    
    group_by(project, x) %>%
    
    summarise(
      Total= sum(quantity)
    )
  )
}
})
```

The idea is that I want to have a reactive data(holidays_data) used for plotting which is grouped by depending on what project was chosen by the user as shown below. For instance if the user selects project A, then the data will be grouped by column 1, B column 2 etc. I wanted to go for this way to avoid repetition of writing the same code for the different columns.

```
holidays_data <- reactive({input$button_g
  switch (
    input$projects,
    "A" = holidays(column1),
    "B" = holidays(column2),
    "C" = holidays(column3)
  )
})
```

With this method it gives me an error saying: 'Unused argument column1'. If someone has any suggestion that will take me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you use `reactive`, you create a function without arguments, so that it doesn't accept column1, but you can put a reactive function inside a function with arguments (the contrary of what you did) and return this reactive, making the function itself reactive.

Comment: Would you mind providing a very short example of how you would do it because I am still getting the same error when I do `function(x){reactive...}`? Thank you!

Comment: could you provide `dput(head(data()))` so that I can provide an example on your data?

Comment: Hi Waldi. Thanks for the fast response. Here is a dput of the data: `structure(list(sell_date = structure(c(18433, 18434, 18435, 18436, 
18437, 18438), class = "Date"), projects = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    quantity = c(10L, 145L, 135L, 146L, 12L, 15L), DE_Holiday = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("non_holiday", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    US_Holiday = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("non_holiday", 
    "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: The reactive switch then would take the form: 
`holidays_data <- reactive({input$button_g
  switch (
    input$projects,
    "A" = holidays(DE_Holiday),
    "B" = holidays(US_Holiday),
    "C" = holidays(DE_Holiday)
  )
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
holidays <- function(input,data,x) {
  reactive({
    input$apply
    #Create symbol from character
    x <- rlang::sym(x)
    isolate(
    data() %>%
        filter(!!x != 'non_holiday' &
               projects %in% input$projects &
               date >= input$sell_date[1] &
               date <= input$sell_date[2]) %>%
        group_by(project, !!x) %>%
        
        summarise(
          Total= sum(quantity)
        )
    )
  })
}
```

This function can be called in a reactive context :

```
holidays(input,data,"DE_Holiday")
```

Comment: I case of error, please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to facilitate correction.